# Display place name when tap on place marker in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to display places within 1 km from my current location on window phone 8 map control with google places API. I am using JSON parsing to fetch latitude, longitude and Name. Now i want name to be display like a tooltip when user tap on any place circle.

//Use google API to show POI

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + position.Coordinate.Latitude + "," + position.Coordinate.Longitude + "&radius=1000&keyword=hospital&key=AIzaSyBCccOYAea2ITvgqNpIHcutuExQwzQctCk";
string googleResult = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);
```

//Parse JSON data

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(googleResult);
JArray jarr = (JArray)obj["results"];

foreach(var item in jarr)
        {
            string name = (string)item.SelectToken("name");
            double lt = (double)item.SelectToken("geometry.location.lat");
            double lg = (double)item.SelectToken("geometry.location.lng");

            //Create a small circle to mark the current location.
            Ellipse myCircle2 = new Ellipse();
            myCircle2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            myCircle2.Height = 10;
            myCircle2.Width = 10;
            myCircle2.Opacity = 50;

            // Create a MapOverlay to contain the circle.
            MapOverlay myLocationOverlay2 = new MapOverlay();
            myLocationOverlay2.Content = myCircle2;
            myLocationOverlay2.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate2 = new GeoCoordinate(lt, lg);
            myLocationOverlay2.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinate2;

            // Create a MapLayer to contain the MapOverlay.
            MapLayer myLocationLayer2 = new MapLayer();
            myLocationLayer2.Add(myLocationOverlay2);

            // Add the MapLayer to the Map.
            Bmap.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer2);

        }
```